# Is it possible to create a Paned Window in a Tab Notebook ? (Python TKinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a pretty complex User Interface, that has multiple Tabs (Notebooks), the Main NoteBook (Initially visible One) needs to have a Paned Window of several Graphs... I cannot seem to find an example of a PanedWindow on a Notebook Tab ?  Is this possible ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand whats the difficulty in creating this. All you have to do is set the parent to the tab.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk                     
from tkinter import ttk 
  
  
root = tk.Tk() 
root.title("Tab Widget") 
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) 
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1') 
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2') 
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both") 

paned_window1 = tk.PanedWindow(tab1, orient = tk.VERTICAL, bg='red', bd=10)
paned_window1.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

paned_window2 = tk.PanedWindow(tab1, orient = tk.VERTICAL, bg='blue', bd=10)
paned_window2.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

label = tk.Label(text='See it is possible')
paned_window1.add(label)

label2 = tk.Label(text='Oh no!')
paned_window2.add(label2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you ... yes that is the approach I want to place a list of selectable names... 1 or more on 1 pane... and plots of graphs on the other